# php image upload directory

Tags: php, security, file-upload, webforms

I am implementing a php site that allows users to upload their pictures, I created the uploads directory at the same level as root but now how can I access those images in html. 
I tried following

```
<img src="../../uploads/<?=$filename?>">
```

Comment: Do you use a framework? Please write example web url that run your php code

Comment: Note that the "src" is required by the browser client, not processed by your server.

Comment: no framework, http://ehtisham9.me/diary is the link.

Comment: That is, whatever you put in the "src" part of the HTML tag is requested by the browser. If you put `../../uploads/abc` in the `src` field your browser will request the page `ehtisham9.me/diary/../../uploads/abc` for the image, and the server should put it there.

Comment: @user202729 I used to do src="uploads/username.jpg" but now I moved that uploads folder out of the root directory (2 dir back)

Comment: actually, i don't want anyone to just go and see all the images in upload dir like ehti**.com/uploads so I moved uploads to out of site's root directory i.e ehtisham**.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a root variable

If you are using php 5.3+

```
<?php 

$root =  __DIR__;

 ?>

 <img src="<?php echo $root ?>uploads/<?=$filename?>">
```

or set the $root variable to your domain name